# Fast Upload, Slow Download on Wireless-AC WAN over SFTP

Tags: file-transfer

Title says most of it.  I use ES File Explorer, but the issue seems to exist in any file manager.  Copying files to the SFTP server nets 20-30MB/s, whereas copying files from is ~400-500kB/s.

I gather this may have something to do with Android treating these copy operations as a background download, but that's mostly supposition.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the site/computer you are downloading from have a upload limit. but when you push files (you upload) the other side is downloading, so it less of a problem for them.

Comment: I wasn't clear, my fault.  This is all over an internal Wireless-AC network.  I'm currently on a device (laptop) that connects to the same SFTP server (desktop, also mine) without this issue.

Comment: In that case try a different application, to make sure it is not the application fault. Some application implement file transfer over the network very poorly.

p.s I had similar problem when both my laptop and my phone where connected via wireless, and the download speed on my phone was very slow (phone downloader/laptop uploader over wifi).

wifi is a shared volume, and only one client can talk at the time.